# How to replace a value in array by another different value in PHP?

Tags: php, arrays

I'm trying to find a way to replace any duplicated value but the only solution I have found so far is array_unique which doesn't really work for me as I need the duplicate to be replaced by another number which itself is not a duplicate.

```
 function generate_random_numbers($rows, $delimiter)
 {
     $numbers = array();

     for($i = 0; $i < $delimiter; $i++)
     {
         $numbers[$i] = rand(1, $rows);

         if(in_array($i, $numbers))
         {
            $numbers[$i] = rand(1, $row);
         }
     }
     return $numbers;
 }

 $numbers = generate_random_numbers(20, 10);

 print_r($numbers);
```

would anyone help me out on this one please?

Comment: you want $delimiter random but different numbers?

Comment: I actually want all the numbers inside $numbers array to be different but within the $row range. **array_unique** will remove the numbers that repeat and I want to have the numbers in $delimiter.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can do this way easier and faster.

Just create an array for all possible numbers with [`range()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.range.php). Then [`shuffle()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.shuffle.php) the array and take an [`array_slice()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-slice.php) as big as you want.

```
<?php

    function generate_random_numbers($max, $amount) {
        if($amount > $max)
            return [];

        $numbers = range(1, $max);
        shuffle($numbers);
        return array_slice($numbers, 0, $amount);
    }

    $numbers = generate_random_numbers(20, 10);
    print_r($numbers);

?>
```

And if you want to get 490 unique elements from a range from 1 - 500, 10'000 times:

- My version: ~ 0.7 secs
- Your version: Order 2 birthday cakes, you will need them.

Answer (score 1):

You are inserting a random number and then, if it is already in the array (which it MUST be because you just inserted it), you use a new random number, which might be a duplicate. So, you have to get a number that is not a duplicate:

```
do {
    $num = rand(1,$rows);
} while(!in_array($num, $numbers));
```

Now, you know that $num is not in $numbers, so you can insert it:

```
$numbers[] = $num;
```

Answer (score 1):

You were pretty close.
The if-clause needs to be a loop, to get new random number.
(Also your in_array was slightly wrong)

```
function generate_random_numbers($rows, $delimiter) {
    $numbers = array();

    for($i = 0; $i < $delimiter; $i++) {
        do {
            $number = rand(1, $rows);
        }
        while(in_array($number, $numbers));

        $numbers[] = $number;
    }

    return $numbers;
 }
```